# Fontlab Studio 5 rendering Low Case 0 as a solid circle?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, adobe-photoshop, fontlab-studio

I have a strange problem and I have tried all sorts suggestions from the net but nothing works.

I am using:
Photoshop 2018
Illustrator 2018
Fontlab Studio 5
Windows.

I am working on a font that I have created but when I Copy & paste the letter "o" into Fontlab Studio the center of the "o" is not rendered (see image).

Here is how I created the font.

1. Created the each letter in Photoshop.
   Width: 331 px
   Height: 300 px
   Resolution: 300 px/inch

Used quick selection tool to find the edges of the character then create Work Path. I then export work path to Illustrator.

2.
Opened the Work Path from Photoshop in Illustrator and selected "Make Compound Path".
I then copied the character to my art board and resized it to fit my font guidelines.

3. Ctrl C to copy the font and then in Fontlab open the character "o" Glyph and Ctrl V to paste my font into the Glyph.

Then I Generate the font, install it within Windows and test it within my program of choice.

But.. No matter what I do I get the same result, a black circle not a letter "o"?
[image: Example]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your "o" character should be made up of 2 shapes, the outer, and the inner circle. You need to set one to be a fill, and another one not to be. This is done by setting the direction of the path. To do this, select the inner shape and go to Contour-->Reverse Contour

Comment: Is this done within photoshop or Illustrator?

Comment: @belinea2010 those steps are done within FontLab, after you paste the glyph...